# Combining two array of objects in JavaScript with checks for existence in second array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I've got the following array in JavaScript:

```
const defaults = [
  {
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    title: "Thing 1"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 2,
    title: "Thing 2"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 3,
    title: "Thing 3"
  }
];
```

And the system will also return a second array that contains the user's version of the above data:

```
const user = [
  {
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    title: "Thing 1"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 3,
    title: "Thing 3"
  }
];
```

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to combine the two arrays in such a way that the result is as follows:

```
// result
// const combined = [
//   {
//     active: true,
//     id: 1,
//     title: 'Thing 1'
//   },
//   {
//     active: false,
//     id: 2,
//     title: 'Thing 2'
//   },
//   {
//     active: true,
//     id: 3,
//     title: 'Thing 3'
//   }
// ]
```

This being where the object in the default array isn't present in the user array, then change the object's active value to `false`. I.e. the object with `id` of `2` isn't present in the user data, therefore the object (with the `id` of `2` in the new combined array) should have have `active` being `false` and not `true`.

Here's what I've tried to do:

```
let combined = [];

for (let item1 of defaults) {
  user.forEach((item2) => {
    if (item1.id === item2.id) {
      combined.push(item2);
    } else {
      item1.active = false;
      combined.push(item1);
    }
  });
}
```

But the result from a `console.log` of `combined` isn't quite right:

```
[
  {
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    title: "Thing 1"
  },
  {
    active: false,
    id: 1,
    title: "Thing 1"
  },
  {
    active: false,
    id: 2,
    title: "Thing 2"
  },
  {
    active: false,
    id: 2,
    title: "Thing 2"
  },
  {
    active: false,
    id: 3,
    title: "Thing 3"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 3,
    title: "Thing 3"
  }
]
```

I think I'm close, but I must be missing something. It also doesn't feel quite right using a `for` loop that contains a `forEach` loop for each item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice simple way only using higher order functions.

```
const combined = defaults.map(item1 => {
    item1.active = user.some(item2 => item1.id === item2.id);
    return item1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const defaults = [
  {
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    title: "Thing 1"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 2,
    title: "Thing 2"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 3,
    title: "Thing 3"
  }
];

const user = [
  {
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    title: "Thing 1"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 3,
    title: "Thing 3"
  }
];

const combined = Object.assign([],user,defaults)
combined.forEach(e=>e.active=user.some(el=>JSON.stringify(el)==JSON.stringify(e)));

console.log(combined)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the result to combined array in both if and else scenarios. You only need to check the item exists in user array too. For that make use of `Array.prototype.find`

```js
const defaults = [
  {
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    title: "Thing 1"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 2,
    title: "Thing 2"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 3,
    title: "Thing 3"
  }
];

const user = [
  {
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    title: "Thing 1"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 3,
    title: "Thing 3"
  }
];
const combined = [];
for (let item1 of defaults) {
  const item2 = user.find((item2) => {
    if (item1.id === item2.id) {
      return true
    } 
  });
  if(item2) {
      combined.push(item2);
  } else {
      item1.active = false;
      combined.push(item1);
  }
}
console.log(combined);
```